# showing a set is not a subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the orthogonal subgroup $O_2$. Show that the set $\{g \in G : g^2= e\}$ is not a subgroup of $G$

The question before says let $G$ be an abelian group and I can see where I have used that fact. It lets us write $a^2b^2=(ab)^2$ and so $ab \in G$. But I cant find a way to 'get out' of $G$.

Comment: HINT: If $g$ and $h$ are elements of the set in question, is it true that the product $gh$ is in there?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Every rotation is a product of two reflections.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your proof you have used that $(gh)^2=g^2h^2.$ You need $G$ to be abelian for this.

In general $(gh)^2=ghgh$ and you cannot swap the inner $h$ and $g$ unless $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks think its time to take a break. This shouldn't have been that hard ;-).

Comment: Of course, $(gh)^2 = ghgh \neq g^2h^2$ is generally true, but you still need to find an explicit example of elements in $G$ with $(gh)^2\neq g^2h^2$.  Other wise, it might have just happened on accident.  For example, if instead of $O_2$, one used $SO_2$, then the corresponding $G$ *would* be a group.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Indeed. $SO_2$ is abelian though. A non-abelian example with the mentioned property is the [quaternion group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group).